# Using SVG as frame for image

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to put images inside the SVG that i had created with Adobe Illustrator. Can someone tell me how to do it and applying the transition to the images. And what type of images that is recommended to use? Here is my SVG code.

```
    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="100 450 2000 2000">
    <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#34c6eb; transition: transform 1s ease; transform-origin: center center; }</style></defs>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M616.08,1356.34A497.88,497.88,0,0,1,469.64,1004.5H843.71c-.05,1.49-.08,2.77-.08,4a124.93,124.93,0,0,0,34.2,86.1Z"  />

    <path d="M843.19,1005c0,1.29-.06,2.42-.06,3.5a125.47,125.47,0,0,0,34,86.09l-261,261.05A497.43,497.43,0,0,1,470.14,1005H843.19m1-1H469.14a498.45,498.45,0,0,0,146.94,353l.5-.5,261.94-261.94a124.59,124.59,0,0,1-34.39-86.11c0-1.51,0-3,.09-4.5Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M1152.44,1094.32a125,125,0,0,0,34.19-86.1c0-1.21,0-2.49-.07-4h374.07a498,498,0,0,1-146.45,351.84Z"/>

    <path d="M1560.12,1004.72a497.38,497.38,0,0,1-145.94,350.63l-261-261a125.43,125.43,0,0,0,34-86.09c0-1.09,0-2.22-.05-3.5h373m1-1H1186q.09,2.24.09,4.5a124.59,124.59,0,0,1-34.39,86.11l262.44,262.43a498.41,498.41,0,0,0,147-353Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M1560.68,1044.47l.23-.23-.23.23Z"/>

    <path d="M1560.91,1044.24l-.23.23h0l.23-.23Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M1002.25,1527.92a497.9,497.9,0,0,1-351.34-145.44l261.22-261.23a124.44,124.44,0,0,0,90.12,38.68Z"/>

    <path d="M912.13,1122a124.82,124.82,0,0,0,89.62,38.46v367a497.36,497.36,0,0,1-350.13-144.94L912.13,1122m0-1.43-261.94,262a498.38,498.38,0,0,0,352.55,145.94v-369a124.64,124.64,0,0,1-90.61-38.9Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M1561.18,1044h0l-.27.27Z"/>

    <path d="M1561.18,1044l-.27.27.27-.26Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M1035.25,1159.21a124.44,124.44,0,0,0,89.62-38.16l261.71,261.71a497.9,497.9,0,0,1-351.33,144.46Z"/>

    <path d="M1124.88,1121.76l261,261a497.42,497.42,0,0,1-350.13,144v-367a124.9,124.9,0,0,0,89.13-38m0-1.43a124.64,124.64,0,0,1-90.12,38.39v369h.5a498.4,498.4,0,0,0,352-145l-262.42-262.43Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M469.39,977.5A497.94,497.94,0,0,1,615.84,625.66L877.58,887.4a124.92,124.92,0,0,0-34.19,86.1c0,1.23,0,2.51.07,4Z"/>

    <path d="M615.84,626.36l261,261a125.46,125.46,0,0,0-34,86.09c0,1.08,0,2.21.05,3.5h-373A497.43,497.43,0,0,1,615.84,626.36m0-1.41a498.42,498.42,0,0,0-147,353H844q-.09-2.24-.09-4.5a124.59,124.59,0,0,1,34.39-86.11L616.34,625.45l-.5-.5Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M648.16,605.43A498,498,0,0,1,999.5,460V828a124.36,124.36,0,0,0-90.12,38.68Z"/>

    <path d="M999,460.49v367a124.86,124.86,0,0,0-89.62,38.46L648.87,605.43A497.36,497.36,0,0,1,999,460.49m1-1A498.43,498.43,0,0,0,647.45,605.43L909.39,867.37A124.67,124.67,0,0,1,1000,828.48v-369Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M1125.12,866.67a124.41,124.41,0,0,0-89.62-38.17v-368A497.95,497.95,0,0,1,1386.84,605Z"/>

    <path d="M1036,461a497.42,497.42,0,0,1,350.13,144l-261,261A124.91,124.91,0,0,0,1036,828V461m-.5-1h-.5V829a124.67,124.67,0,0,1,90.12,38.38L1387.54,605a498.36,498.36,0,0,0-352-145Z"/>

    <path class="cls-1" d="M1186.71,977.22c0-1.5.08-2.78.08-4a124.91,124.91,0,0,0-34.2-86.1l261.74-261.74a497.94,497.94,0,0,1,146.45,351.84Z"/>

    <path d="M1414.33,626.08a497.45,497.45,0,0,1,146,350.64h-373c0-1.29.06-2.42.06-3.5a125.43,125.43,0,0,0-34-86.09l261-261m0-1.41L1151.89,887.11a124.56,124.56,0,0,1,34.4,86.11c0,1.5,0,3-.09,4.5h375.08a498.42,498.42,0,0,0-147-353.05Z"/>

    <circle class="cls-1" cx="1015" cy="994" r="124.5"/>

    <path d="M1015,870a124,124,0,1,1-87.68,36.32A123.19,123.19,0,0,1,1015,870m0-1a125,125,0,1,0,125,125,125,125,0,0,0-125-125Z"/>

</svg>

    .cls-1:hover{
            transform: scale(1.1);
            cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried placing <image href="C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Image test\1-image.png" height="200" width="200" /> in different places but still doesn't work. And i wanted to put different images on each part.

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/sirko/9d5z6Lhp/ . Note that you viewBox is shifted, so you need to put the image within the visible area.

Comment: What i want to achieve is to replace the colour to my image actually

Comment: like that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Comment: No but if using that as an example i wanted to change the red colour of the heart to my own image. Is that doable?

Comment: Apply the clip-path to the image and put the animation on that?